# Keyboard Status Led after Suspending

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, suspend

I have a relativly wired question.
When I start my Laptop there is missing any driver connection or so which can tell my keyboard if eg. the CapsLock is active. And my keboard can tell Ubuntu the current keyboard brightness.

After a lot of testing. I figured out that ther must be any driver because:

1. My Keboard works except for the Status leds and the function Keys like volume up/down
2. I can control my keybord brigthness over the settings even though if I change ich via shortcut the settings slider won't be updated.

Then I figured out that if I suspend my Laptop and wake it up again. All works fine the function keys the  status led and when I change my keyboard brigthness there pops a dialog which shows the current state.

Does somebody have an Idea how to archieve that my keyboard work also on first startup. What does suspending what powering on doesn't do?

**If somebody has the same issue, please upvote the question**